# How to use AObject in the AddCheckBox function when using the componentslist?

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to understand the AddCheckBox function in inno pascal script. The documentation is limited:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses

```
 function AddCheckBox(const ACaption, ASubItem: String; ALevel: Byte; AChecked, AEnabled, AHasInternalChildren, ACheckWhenParentChecked: Boolean; AObject: TObject): Integer;
```

How to use the "AObject" argument? Of course I can just use "nil" but this causes an error message about a memory once the user clicks on the added checkbox.

It may be relevant that I want to add a checkbox to the componentslist (dynamically) of the WizardForm. So it is something like:

```
 WizardForm.ComponentsList.AddCheckbox(..please help me with the correct arguments).
```

The function seems useful but to use it, I need to know what arguments to use and what they mean.

Comment: Even though `AObject` is an optional parameter for storing an object instance of your choice, you cannot manually add entries to the `ComponentsList` at runtime this way because that list stores the component data to that object field and expects them there.